# Unable to closed Sliding menu in iOS

Tags: ios, slidingmenu, swrevealviewcontroller

[image]

in my application create sliding menu using **SWRevealViewController**
when i click on uiviewcontroller  sliding menu not close automatically if view controller contain tableview on other  click event 
how can i solved this problem 
my code is :

```
 SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: r u added the  custom **SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController** segue on selection part in side menu

Comment: if you don't mine can you send your project  I check and solve your issue'

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using this :-

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
[revealController panGestureRecognizer];
[revealController tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.menueBtn addTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

selector (revealToggle:)call SWRevealViewController class

Answer (score 0):

Write this code on your green view `viewdidload` method to  navigate to another view.

```
revealController=[[SWRevealViewController alloc]init];
revealController = [self revealViewController];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
revealController.delegate=self;
[revealController panGestureRecognizer];

[revealController tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do

Comment: i already upload image in my question . You can see green view in right side. and green view is my tableview cell. so i want to  when i click on this cell, my sliding menu will have to closed